# Getting Sum of a Column in Daily

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i need a query for my SQL 2008 R2 that compute sum of a column based on date like

Dates

```
10/7/2013 12:28:30
10/7/2013 01:28:30 
10/7/2013 03:04:30 
10/8/2013 06:03:51
```

Amounts

```
100
102
200
300
```

I need the total amount for the date 10/7/2013
TotalAmount
402

Comment: How do you you know what amount goes to what day?

Comment: i prefer base in row on each table

Answer (score 1):

The range filter below removes the time portion of the input and compares it to a one day span. Keeping the expression on the right side of the where clause allows you to use an index on your date column.

Dont do: <s>`where convert(date, getdate()) = @day`</s> which would cause a table scan.

**Do this instead**:

```
declare @yourTable table (dt datetime, qty int );
    insert into @yourTable
        select '10/7/2013 12:28:30', 100 union all
        select '10/7/2013 01:28:30', 102 union all
        select '10/7/2013 03:04:30', 200 union all
        select '10/8/2013 06:03:51', 300;

    declare @day datetime;
    set @day = '10/7/2013'

    select  sum(qty) 
    from    @yourTable
    where   dt >= dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, @day), 0) and 
            dt < dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, @day), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you "group by" you're grouping by the date & time.  You need to reformat the datetime column, so its grouping by just a date.

There's lots of ways to do that.  An example:

```
select CONVERT (date, GETDATE());
```

Converts current datetime to a date.

([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dacd95a1-a0b0-44d5-bcf5-ea407285aa9f/converting-datetime-data-to-show-date-only))